# How do I figure out my logic flaw?

Tags: ruby, find, union, nodes

I'm having trouble figuring out my logic flaw.

`3` is a parent of `4` and `8` is the parent of `3`. I want `9` to point to the root of `4` which is `8`.

This is my Ruby class:

```
class QuickUnion

  def initialize(n)
    @id = Array.new(n) {|i| i}
  end

  def root(i)
    while i != @id[i] do
      i = @id[i]
    end
    i
  end

  def connected?(p, q)
    root(p) == root(q)
  end

  def union(p, q)
     @id[p] = @id[q]
  end

  def print_union
    puts "#{@id}"
  end

end
```

This is the test file:

```
qu = QuickUnion.new(10)
qu.print_union
qu.union(4,3)
qu.print_union
qu.union(3,8)
qu.print_union
qu.union(6,5)
qu.print_union
qu.union(9,4)
qu.print_union
```

This is the output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 8, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 8, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 8, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 3]
```

The output for the last array should be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 8, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Guess I should explain what I'm trying to do better, so 3 is a parent of 4 and 8 is the parent of 3. I want 9 to point to the root of 4 which is 8.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your union method with the following:

```
def union(p, q)
     @id[p] = root(@id[q])
end
```

*There are many ways to achieve this, I found this the easiest (as helper functions are already in place)*

Comment: Ahhh, why didn't I see that before?  Thank you!!

Comment: Happens with all of us, glad I could help..

Answer (score 1):

`union(9,4)` is assigning `@id[9] = @id[4] = 3`.

In ruby, the index of an array starts with 0, not 1.